# CLI stopped working when running php artisan serve - Laravel 4 Win7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, php

I added a path to my environment variables : `C:\wamp\bin\php`

When I run the command `php artisan serve` it says

```
Laravel development server started on `http://localhost:8000`
```

But after that a dialog pops up up saying `CLI has stopped working...`

Anyone know the reason for this dialog box popping up? Would really like to find out

Comment: and still no answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `php artisan serve &` - you should still be able to use the command line whilst it's serving.

Otherwise, try running `php artisan serve`, then opening a new CLI window and doing your other commands in there.